# Cyclic linear codes and idempotents

Tags: polynomials, coding-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials, idempotents

Got this assignment from coding class and would be very thankful for checking if my solutions are correct.

a) Find all idempotents modulo $1 + x^{17}$ of degree at most $15$

So first i find $r$ from $1=2^r mod17$ so $r=8$.

Next step is to find idempotents by partitioning $Zn$ into classes:
$C_0 = \{ 0 \}; C_1 = \{ 1,2,4,16,15,13,9 \}; C_3 = \{ 3,5,6,7,10,11,12,14 \}$

Here I don't know if I've done this step correct because $C_2$ was just like $C_1$ but missing the $1$ in the set. Should i treat it as another class?

The rest of the sets are the same, so i assume there is some pattern for finding all of them. them (further there are just multipliers[sry I'm neither native english nor a math student so dont know if this term is used correctly, but I hope You know what I mean]) Are there usually only 3 such sets?

From the obtained sets i got idempotents for a which are at most degree $15$: $\{1, x^3+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^{10}+x^{11}+x^{12}+x^{14}, 1+x^3+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^{10}+x^{11}+x^{12}+x^{14}\}$

b) How many cyclic linear codes (other than $\{00...0\}$ and $K^n$) are there if $n = 17$? And if $n = 136$?

So the number of cyclic linear codes is equal to the number of idempotents? for $n=17$ it was 7, so 7 linear codes. Don't know if the formula i've found for calculating this was correct but seems right $2^{n}-1$ where $n$ is the number of sets obtained? How to find for $136$?

c)Let $I(x)$ be the idempotent in (a) in which the constant term equals zero and the coeficient
of $x^
3$
is non-zero. Find the generator polynomial of the smallest cyclic linear code of length 17
containing $I(x)$. What is the dimension of that code?

I just obtained the $GCD(1+x^{17}, x^3+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^{10}+x^{11}+x^{12}+x^{14})$, which is the generator polynomial for the cyclic linear code. Not sure about the dimension? Is it equal to $n-r$?

Comment: Cyclotomic cosets do form a partition (BTW you left out 8 from $C_1$) meaning that if $i$ belongs to $C_j$, then $C_i=C_j$. We have $1\equiv 2^8=2\cdot 2^7\pmod{17}$, so $1\in C_2$. How did you get $7$ as the answer in part A? The codes corresponding to idempotents $0$ and $1$ were left out as trivial, so only $e_0+e_1$, $e_0+e_2$, $e_0+e_1+e_2$, $e_1$, $e_2$ and $e_1+e_2$ can be used, right? ($e_0$ gives the trivial code. As $136=8\cdot17$ you get $$x^{136}+1=(x^{17}+1)^8$$ and can use this calculation, but there are more possibilities, because the ring is no longer semisimple.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank You! I think you meant part B. In my notes i've found that ` To find all cyclic codes of length x, we simply find all idempotent polynomials and find the corresponding generator polynomial`. So here i had 7 idempotents, corresponding to 7 generator polynomials. But now as i look at this i think its not everything? (In that 7 I had also $I(x)=1$)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen ah ok sry now i know what to do more in B (my lack of knowledge + spending too much on reading came out here). From every of the 7 polynomials in generating matrix i have to get all the cyclic codes by performing the shifts on them and making all the possible combinations

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen so for example: in code with $n=6$ i have a generating polynomial $x+1$ which produces the following 5 codewords $\begin{bmatrix}
 1&  1& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0&  1&  1&  0&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  0& 1&  1&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0& 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  1& 
1\end{bmatrix}$  and i have to do it for every generating polynomial :) (so just calculating length - dimension of generating polynomial)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to comment the question about dimension of the code. The simple rule is: if the length of the code is $n$ and the degree of the generator polynomial is $r$, then the dimension of the code is $n-1-r$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank You! I assume my explanation how to find the cyclic codes from generator polynomials is correct? except its length - degree od generatin polynomial, not dimension

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I've calculated the amount of codewords and for $n=17$ it is 10 so i assume for 136 it is $8*10$ ?